# Scrapy return empty array

Tags: python, xpath, css-selectors, scrapy

I want to use Scrapy for crawl. so i open firefox or chrome for xpath or css selector to copy this address! and i got it! but this return empty! i try this with jquery in online site(inspect element) and in response.body . both of them is same but it doesnt work! fir example, my page for crawl is [this](http://ketab.ir/modules.php?name=News&op=pirbook&bcode=1938570)
and addresses are:

```
IN INSPECT ELEMENT:
{
FIREFOX CSS:
html body table tbody tr td div table tbody tr td center table tbody tr td table tbody tr td table.borderact tbody tr td h1
FIREFOX XPATH:
/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[3]/center/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/h1

CHROME CSS: 
body > table > tbody > tr > td > div > table:nth-child(3) > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(3) > center > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(3) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td > h1


IN RESPONSE:

FIREFOX CSS:
html body table tbody tr td div table tbody tr td center table tbody tr td table tbody tr td table.\"borderact\" tbody tr td h1
FIREFOX XPATH:
/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[3]/center/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/h1
 CHROME CSS: 
 body > table > tbody > tr > td > div > table:nth-child(3) > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(3) > center > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(3) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td > h1
}
```

Comment: `<tbody>` are usually inserted by browsers to make the HTML conformant. Website authors usually omit the `<tbody>`. Scrapy sees the "raw" HTML through `lxml` by default, and does not try to make it conformant. So try dropping the `tbody/` step in your XPath.